# Change CGRect or Override CGRect

Tags: ios, radial-gradients

I am drawing a radial gradient in quartz.
I created a new file and put the code  in `drawRect` as

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//Draw the gray Gradient

CGFloat BGLocations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
CGFloat BgComponents[8] = { 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 , 1.0,  // Start color
   0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 1.0 }; // Mid color and End color
CGColorSpaceRef BgRGBColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef bgRadialGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(BgRGBColorspace, BgComponents, BGLocations, 2);


CGPoint startBg = CGPointMake(250, 250); 
CGFloat endRadius= 250;


CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, bgRadialGradient, startBg, 0, startBg, endRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
CGColorSpaceRelease(BgRGBColorspace);
CGGradientRelease(bgRadialGradient);
```

Now i am making a `UIView` and initializing it with the `RadialGradientView` created through the [website](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.ca/2011/07/draw-radial-gradient-in-quartz.html) but i need to change the `endRadius` according to the different implementations.

IS there a way to do that.

I am initializing the UIView with Frame.

```
UIView* backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];

    UIView* gradientView = [[RadialGradientView alloc] initWithFrame: backgroundView.bounds];
```

So when i am trying to access endRadius property of gradientView, Its not showing up.

Comment: can u explain this "when i am trying to access endRadius property of gradientView" ?

Comment: how u r trying to access endRadius ?

Comment: I am implementing drawRect function in RadialGradientView class . ((void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect { above mentioned function })  and i am initializing it through initWithFrame  backgroundView. But now i need to have endRadius changed for different implementation. I dont know how to implement that

Comment: I tried overriding function **- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect withEndRadiusMultiplierToHeight:(CGFloat)endRadiusMultiplier** but that too did not held. Declared endRadiusMultiplier as property.

Comment: u should not change drar REct method implementation

Comment: Do i need to override initWithFrame . I am unable to understand how to initialize the UIView created by RadialGradientView class with EndRadius as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `endRadius` as a property in your subclassed yourView.h file as

```
@property(assign) CGFloat endRadius;
```

and you can access this property like:

```
   yourView.endRadius=40;
```

and in the code , change this line:

```
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, bgRadialGradient, startBg, 0, startBg, endRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
```

to

```
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, bgRadialGradient, startBg, 0, startBg, self.endRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
```

or

```
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, bgRadialGradient, startBg, 0, startBg, _endRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
```

Comment: HI, can you  look at the question again . I have changed a little but according to your answer.